# iOS: Looking for NSDictionary value I get error: [__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instanc

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm getting Json response with subArrays of dictionaries and I'm looking for particular value inside of one the subArrays. This is the subArray I care about:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x600000047680>(
{
    value = "VeryImportanValue";
},
{
    value = "someValue";
},
{
    value = 0912131235235234;
}
)
```

I'm looking for the dictionary with the value of "VeryImportanValue". But as you can see you of the values are numeric and I check:

if ([[dict objectForKey:@"value"]isEqualToString:@"VeryImportanValue"])

I get this error:

```
 -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

But switch the if statement to fix the error above:

```
 if ([[[dict objectForKey:@"value"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"VeryImportanValue"])
```

I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

How can I check the value of the dictionary without getting any of this errors regarless if is string or numeric value?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method that turns the unknown object into a string:

```
- (NSString *)stringForStringOrNumber:(id)object
{
    NSString *result = nil;
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        result = object;
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        result = [object stringValue];
    } else {
        result = @"I can't guess";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could.... but turning everything into a string is likely slow and probably imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do isEqualToString, you should first check the value type of your dictionary.

```
  if(dict[@"value"]isKindOfClass==[NSString class]) //value is string
```

Comment: Or maybe something that compiles.  :)